# pictures not displaying on github gh-pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I work on my project recently and it works fine in my localhost.
But when I host it on github gh-pages, all pictures are not displaying.
I know it is case-sensitive and have been checking the uppercase/lowercase and the relative path as well, but still the pictures are not showing.

Any solutions?

here are the image path:

```
<img class="thumnail" src=".././images/picture1.jpg">
<img class="thumnail" src=".././images/picture2.jpg"
```

folder structure is like this:

```
images
    picture1.jpg
    picture2.jpg
Dist
    index.html
    style.css
```

Comment: You probably want to provide the html/javascript which includes the image paths.

Comment: I have added the image paths.

Answer (score 1):

solved it! I moved the images folder into dist folder and deploy it again and it works! and I changed the path to

```
<img class="thumnail" src="images/picture1.jpg">
```